# Laravel - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-4

I'm running my laravel site in my localhost, works fine. But when I try run my site in hosting server, I got 500 internal server error? Is it because of my .htaccess file or [I remove public url](http://creolab.hr/2013/03/removing-the-public-segment-in-a-laravel-4-app/) ?

My .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have some informations about the remote and your local system?

Comment: what do you mean? I'm not following.

Comment: Windows, Mac or Linux? What do you use on the systems? What is if you remove the mod_negotiation.c? And if you rewrite at least the mod_rewrite module block? Then you can be shure that you have an syntax error.

Comment: check host PHP version

Answer (score 2):

Try this on the terminal :

```
sudo chmod -R 755 <your_laravel_project>
```

and

```
chmod -R o+w <your_laravel_project>/storage
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using a supported version of PHP and that your folders have `755` permission.

You can also check the Laravel's log file to learn a bit more about what caused the 500 error.
If there is no entry in the log file, the problem might come from the .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with my shared hosting provider.
Laravel uses the `public` folder for files that are directly accessible for the visitors browser. This should be the webspace root on the shared hosting.

The problem occurs, when the `index.php` in `/public` is called and it tries to access files outside (a level above) the webspace root. Normally this is not allowed.

You (or your hosting provider) need to change the `open_basedir` value in php settings.

On my hosting it looked like this:

```
{WEBSPACEROOT}{/}{:}{TMP}{/}
```

I changed it to

```
{WEBSPACEROOT}{/}{:}{TMP}{/}{:}{WEBSPACEROOT}{/../}
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try following commands one by one. I hope my solution will solve your problem.

```
find <laravel_project_path> -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

find <laravel_project_path> -type d -exec chmod ug+s {} \;

find <laravel_project_path> -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

chown -R www-data:www-data <laravel_project_path>

chmod -R 777 <laravel_project_path>/storage

chmod -R 777 <laravel_project_path>/bootstrap/cache/

find <laravel_project_path>/vendor -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```